# Why do author use a Coset of a group instead of the Group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, coloring

Read the following problem found in [the document, on page 50:](https://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/%7Eluks/iso.pdf)

Input: A set of generators for a $2$-subgroup, $G$, of symmetric group $\rm Sym(A)$, where $A$ is a colored set.

Find: A set of generators for the subgroup $\{\sigma \in  G|\; \sigma \; \text{is color preserving}\}$.

**QUESTION:**

We need $\mathscr{C}_{B_{i}}(G)$ but why do author asking for $\mathscr{C}_{B_{i}}(\sigma G)$ where $\sigma \in \rm Sym(A)$ in problem 2 on page 50 ?

EDIT 1:

In this context, $G=\rm Aut_e(X_r)$ is the subgroup of symmetric group $\rm Sym(A)$ is ,

where $A$ is the collection of all subsets of $V(X_r)$ of size one, two, or three for all $r, r-1, \cdots 1$

and $A$ is a colored set of at most $5$ colors (see page 49).

We have to find aset of generators,

for the subgroup $\{\sigma \in  G=\rm Aut_e(X_r)|\; \sigma \; \text{is color preserving}\}= \mathscr{C}_A(G)=\mathscr{C}_{A}(\rm Aut_e(X_r))=$ the color
preserving elements in $\rm Aut_e(X_r)$ in its action on $A$.

WHAT ARE WE DOING?

Our objective is to obtain $\rm Aut_e(X_r+1)$ from $\rm Aut_e(X_r)$,

in order to do that, we need $K_r$ (the kernel of $\pi_r$),

and $\pi_r(\rm Aut_e(X_r+1))$ (the image of $\pi_r$, see page 48).

Notice, from the proposition $2.3$, on pge 49, we find that,  $\mathscr{C}_A(G)=\mathscr{C}_{A}(\rm Aut_e(X_r))=\pi_r(\rm Aut_e(X_r+1))$,

because, by stabilizing $A_1, A_2, A`$, all $5$ colored sets of sets,

are preserved by $\pi_r(\rm Aut_e(X_r+1))$ **, this is the insinuation of author, no direct proof is given**.

HOW ARE GOING TO DO THAT?

Since, $\pi_r(\rm Aut_e(X_r+1))$ is a subgroup of $\rm Aut_e(X_r)$, and $\mathscr{C}_A(G)=\pi_r(\rm Aut_e(X_r+1))$, so $\mathscr{C}_A(G)$ is a group.

To find $\mathscr{C}_A(G)$, we divide/partition the set $A$ into $k$ subsets $B_1, B_2 \cdots B_k$, such that each $B_i, 1\leq i \leq k$ is $G$-stable.

In other words, $A$ is the disjoint union of $B_1, B_2 \cdots B_k$, such that each $G(B_i)=B_i$. According to the property $(ii)$ on page 50, we can construct $\mathscr{C}_A(G)$ using $G$-stable sets $B_1, B_2 \cdots B_k$ as following:
$$\mathscr{C}_A(G)= \mathscr{C}_{B_{1}}(\mathscr{C}_{B_{2}}( \cdots \mathscr{C}_{B_{k}}(G)))$$

Edit 2:

I notice that union of cosets $\mathscr{C}_{B_{i}}(\sigma G)$ construct the the group $G$, but we are trying to find $\mathscr{C}_{B_{i}}(G)$, not $G$, then why we need $\mathscr{C}_{B_{i}}(\sigma G)$?

Edit 3:

That was my initial thought as our goal is to find ${\mathscr C}_B(G)$, so partitioning into cosets reduces the problem, but then I found the first equation ${\mathscr C}_B(\sigma G) = {\mathscr C}_B(\sigma H) \cup {\mathscr C}_B(\sigma \tau H)$ on page 51, now in the trivalent case $\sigma=1$(identity), could $\sigma \neq 1$? There is no indication it will not happen in the bounded valence case. We need ${\mathscr C}_B(G)$, not ${\mathscr C}_B(\sigma G)$, as $\cup {\mathscr C}(G)=G$ which we already have.

Comment: If you read page 49 of the paper, you will see that the input is ${\rm Aut}_e(X_r)$, and we are assuming at this point that we have generators of this group. The aim now is to find generators of ${\rm Aut}_e(X_{r+1})$.

Comment: In Edit 3 you have written "we need $\mathscr{C}_B(G)$,  not $\mathscr{C}_B(\sigma G)$". But $\mathscr{C}_B(G)$ is a special case of $\mathscr{C}_B(\sigma G)$. If we know how to calculate $\mathscr{C}_B(\sigma G)$ then we can calculate $\mathscr{C}_B(G)$ by calculating $\mathscr{C}_B(\sigma G)$ with $\sigma=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read on to the bottom of page 50, you will see that, in the case when $G$ acts transitively but imprimitively on $B$, we split $B$ into two disjoint $G$-blocks $B_1$ and $B_2$, and then $G = H \cup \tau H$, where $H$ is the stabilizer of $B$ in $G$, and $\tau \in G$ satisfies $\tau(B_1) = B_2$.

Now we use the fact that ${\mathscr C}_B(H \cup \tau H) = {\mathscr C}_B(H) \cup {\mathscr C}_B(\tau H)$, and so, in the  solution to Problem 2,  we compute ${\mathscr C}_B(G)$ as this union, which means solving two instances of the same problem on $H$ and the coset $\tau H$, both of which have size $|G|/2$.

So now it should be clear why we need to be able to solve Problem 2 for cosets as well as groups: we have to be able to solve it for $\tau H$.

Comment: That was my initial thought as our goal is to find ${\mathscr C}_B(G)$, so partitioning into cosets reduces the problem, but then I found the first equation ${\mathscr C}_B(\sigma G) = {\mathscr C}_B(\sigma H) \cup {\mathscr C}_B(\sigma \tau H)$ on page 51, now in the trivalent case $\sigma=1$(identity), could $\sigma \neq 1$? There is no indication it will not happen in the bounded valence case. Your explanation is valid when $\sigma = 1$, not when $\sigma \neq 1$, because we need ${\mathscr C}_B(G)$, not ${\mathscr C}_B(\sigma G)$, as $\cup {\mathscr C}(G)=G$ which we already have.

Comment: I don't know what  you mean. In the paper, the author describes how to solve Problem 2 for all $\sigma$. We can then solve Problem 1 by applying Problem 2 with $\sigma = 1$.

Comment: When we implement the GI algo for trivalent and bounded valence (only these two cases exist in the paper) is it always  $\sigma=1$? I know for trivalent case, $\sigma=1$ but not sure about the bounded valence case. If the answer to my question is no, then when $\sigma \neq 1$? If the answer is yes, then in the entire paper you don't need  ${\mathscr C}_B(\sigma G) $, with $\sigma \neq 1$ then what is the motivation/reason of a generalization of ${\mathscr C}_B( G)$ as ${\mathscr C}_B(\sigma G), \sigma \neq 1$ when you don't need it in the entire paper? why do u do that? thanks.

Comment: But it isn't always $\sigma = 1$ in the trivalent case. I thought I had explained that in my answer, You also need to solve the problem for $\tau H$, so in that case you are solving it with $\sigma = \tau \ne 1$.

Comment: I see, you are right, so why not write ${\mathscr C}_B(G) = {\mathscr C}_B( H) \cup {\mathscr C}_B(\tau H)$ instead of ${\mathscr C}_B(\sigma G) = {\mathscr C}_B(\sigma H) \cup {\mathscr C}_B(\sigma \tau H)$ (1st equation, page 51), at this point we know how to find ${\mathscr C}_B(\tau H)$, so why do still keep writing ${\mathscr C}_B(\sigma G) $ ? Just to be consistent with the previous part? Would it be wrong if it simply written as ${\mathscr C}_B(G) = {\mathscr C}_B( H) \cup {\mathscr C}_B(\tau H)$ ? thanks.

Comment: We write $\mathscr{C}_B(\sigma G)$, because at this stage we are describing a solution to Problem 2, which is to compute $\mathscr{C}_B(\sigma G)$ for arbitrary $\sigma$.